# cannot find symbol @Type(type = "list-array")error when upgrade to spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, gradle, java-17

Below is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.0.2'
        springCloudVersion = '2022.0.0-M3'
    }
...
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.8'
    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55:2.20.0'
```

below is my entity class,

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.ListArrayType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Jacksonized
@Table(name = "students_stored_row")
@Entity(name = "studentDAO")
public class StudentDAO {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(name = "course", columnDefinition = "text[]")
    private List<String> courses;
    private List<String> coursePath;
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private List<Address> address;
 
}
```

I have recently upgraded the spring boot version to springBootVersion = '3.0.2' and hibernate to 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55:2.20.0'. Gradle version in my local : gradle-7.4.1. Upon running the ./gradlew clean build I observed the below error,

```
error: cannot find symbol
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
          ^
  symbol:   method type()
  location: @interface Type

 error: cannot find symbol
    @Type(type = "list-array")
          ^
  symbol:   method type()
  location: @interface Type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you need to use `value` parameter with class implementing the `UserType` interface as per documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Type.html

Comment: please add some example code

Comment: This is really not a useful answer at all without going further into detail. Like what specifically are the `UserType`s that correspond to `jsonb` and `list-array`? The Hibernate documentation here is...not great.

This goes into a bit more detail: https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/#JSONB_mapping_in_Hibernate_6

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@TypeDef(
    name = "list-array",
    typeClass = ListArrayType.class
)
public class StudentDAO {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Type(type = "list-array")
    @Column(name = "course", columnDefinition = "text[]")
    private List<String> courses;
    private List<String> coursePath;
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private List<Address> address;
 
}
```